# База данных на андроиде, помогите

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Разобрался с SQLite для андроид. Однако, насколько я понял, это чисто локальная база данных, а мне хотелось бы узнать, как организовать приложение, в котором пользователи должны обращаться к базе данных, которая стоит, например, у меня на сервере. Опишите, пожалуйста, общую концепцию, как это сделать

Comment: Подумайте как сформулировать более  конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Поднять REST-сервис, который будет дёргать приложение, а он уже базу.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подключаться к базе через REST API.
Если у вас новый проект, то, советую поставить OrientDB или RethinkDB, в которых уже есть REST API, и клиенты к REST на языке Java. 
Если же старая c SQL, то, советую поставить https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api